# Windows Forms (VB.net) Get NEXT value from Sequence

Tags: vb.net, sequence, assign

I am trying to learn VB.Net & Started building a Windows form using Typed Datasets. I have created one Sequence "OrderHeader_Seq" (SQL Server 2014, Express) and want to assign the latest sequence value to one of the textboxes available with my form while the default navigator "Save" button is pressed and totally lost.

```
    Private Sub OrdersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OrdersBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click

'       
        Me.Validate()
        Me.OrdersBindingSource.EndEdit()

' This area I want to add some kind of coding and assign the value to textbox

        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.POSDataSet)

    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I quit using `Typed DataSets` years ago as they seem to be buggy - good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Open the DataSet in design 
Right click the "TableAdaptor" and add new query 
[image: Add Query 1]
Select "Use SQL Statements" 
[image: Add Query 2]
Select "Which Returns a single value" 
[image: Add Query 3] 
Type in appropriate SQL query. I've defined a sequence called OrderHeaderId_Seq with the database, hence my query is "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR OrderHeaderId_Seq" 
[image: Add Query 4]

Assign an appropriate name for your new scalar query.
[image: Add Query 5]

Ignore the warning, that is generic because the Query statement could not be parsed at the given point of time. 
[image: Add Query 6]

Open the code page for your form and make changed under Save button click event as seen with the image 
[image: Add Query 7]

Now you are good to go!